# How to solve the following non-homogenous linear recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

find the particular solution for:

[image: picture contains the problem and the solution]
can someone show me how to get the answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

The particular solution will be of the form $a_n=\lambda n+\mu$ as the only function within the recurrence relation used is a polynomial of degree $1$. Plugging in this solution gives
$$\lambda n+\mu=\lambda (n-1)+\mu+\lambda (n-2)+\mu+2n$$
$$\lambda n+\mu=2\lambda n+2\mu-3\lambda+2n$$
$$\lambda n+\mu-3\lambda=-2n$$
$$\implies\lambda=-2,\mu=-6$$
Hence the particular solution is
$$a_n=-2n-6$$

Comment: how did you go from step 3 to step 4?

Comment: Comparing coefficients of $n$ and the constant terms.